# 3d to 2d conversion formula

Tags: python

I have an exported JSON from Blender. I have 3d and 2d key points for each of the frames of a video. I want to project these 3d key points on a 2d plane. How can I convert the 3d keypoint so that it can be overlayed on video?

[image: screenshot of the code]

However, I have made a Python script using which I can load 2d key points on video, and 2d the key points are being loaded correctly.

But now the client is asking for a Python script to load 3d key points on video. I have worked on dozens of videos in Blender having lakhs of frames but if I am not able to make this script then all my work will be rejected, so please Blender team please help me.

This requires a lot of mathematical knowledge to project 3d points on a 2d plane but since Blender software converts 3d to 2d it knows what formula is being used inside the software to convert 3d to 2d. So please share that formula so that using camera extrinsic/intrinsic parameters I can convert 3d to 2d.

I need a pure Python/Blender-independent Python script to overlay these 3d key points on video. However, I can overlay 2d points on video I am also sharing a Python script to overlay 2d key points on video so that you understand what type of script I need for 3d points.

I want a similar script that takes 3d key points rather than 2d key points and overlays them on the video frame-by-frame.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post images or screenshots of your code, console or error messages. Instead copy-paste the actual text into your post using [proper code tags](https://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), so it can be indexed and searched for, and other users trying to help don't have to type it by hand themselves which is both error prone and time consuming.

Comment: Most likely nobody will take time to recopy the code from an image. Please add it directly as formated code/text in the question. Also a sample json file may be useful here.

Comment: I've tried to make your question more readable and fix the typos. But I don't know what means *"... having lakhs of frames..."*. Do you mean "... having lots of frames..."?

Comment: To be honest, I still don't understand what you want to do. You have a video file and some 2d or 3d point data ... and you project the 2d data somehow on the video. How? What is the result? What means "project"? Now, your final question is how to project 3d key points. But that's hard to answer if we don't understand the first part with the 2d points. Also, this site is about Blender. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask for a Blender-independent/pure Python solution. It looks like you're looking for some kind of vector math.

Comment: And it seems there is nothing related to Blender here.

Comment: @lemon or is it, if there's a Blender-specific solution? This is always tricky to me.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to project 3D coordinates into camera view. There is a method for that:

`bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view()`

Returns the camera space coords for a 3d point.

Where (0, 0) is the bottom left and (1, 1) is the top right of the camera frame.

[Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.object_utils.html)